Smooth slide on details disclosure not working (using jQuery slideUp)?
I'm sure Im just missing something silly here, but I'm pulling my hair out trying to understand what's going wrong here. I have a details disclosure section that I'm trying to use slideUp and slideDown to enable a smooth transition when a user clicks on the tab, whether they are opening or closing it. And half of it is done, it slides open fine, but it just snaps itself back shut. I added console logs to make sure nothing weird was going on, but no errors and console logs all showing fine makes this tricky to figure out. Code and Codepen below. Thanks in advance for any advice!
<div class="outreach">
<details class="outreach-tab">
  <summary class="tab-title">
    Detail Header
  </summary>
  <div class="prose max-w-none outreach-details">
    Vestibulum vitae suscipit magna, in vehicula neque. Morbi ut dolor lorem. Quisque mattis metus rhoncus massa mollis imperdiet. Sed eleifend risus metus, id suscipit nisi dictum id. Vestibulum rhoncus dui vitae nunc pellentesque, vitae pellentesque neque condimentum. 
  </div>
</details>
</div>

And the accompanying SCSS:
.resource,
.outreach {
  .outreach-tab {
    summary {
      padding: 20px;
      background: #ccdbe5;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #333333;
      cursor: pointer;
      font-size: 120%;
      font-weight: bold;
      
      text-transform: uppercase;
      position: relative;
    }

    .outreach-details {
      background: #ffffff;
      padding: 20px;
      margin-top: 10px;
      display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    }
  }
}

And then finally the JS:
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  $("details").on("toggle", function () {
    const detailsElement = $(this).find(".outreach-details");

    if (this.open) {
      detailsElement.slideDown();
    } else {
      detailsElement.slideUp();
    }
  });
});

If you want to see it broken in the wild, here's a codepen replicating the problem :)
https://codepen.io/jcforrester/pen/mdZjodd

I think instead of toggle event you should use click because when the detail is toggling to close state, its transition is not displayed. In the click event handler, check for the state of open and if it is true, first apply the closing animation and at the end of the transition (you need another event handler for this), change the state to close (more accurately not open).

Also, this might be useful : How to fully animate the details HTML element with only CSS, no JavaScript
